# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method ... on channel ...)

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin-native

very standard code but have no idea why I get 
*Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getHello on channel com.jetbrains.handson.mpp.mobile/createApplicationScreenMessage)*

```
package com.example.mysharedproject

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import android.util.Log
import com.jetbrains.handson.mpp.mobile.createApplicationScreenMessage
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant


class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "com.jetbrains.handson.mpp.mobile/createApplicationScreenMessage")
            .setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
                if (call.method == "getHello"){
                    result.success(createApplicationScreenMessage())
                }
                else{
                    result.notImplemented()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

this code is from SharedCode like in this tutorial 
https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Targeting%20iOS%20and%20Android%20with%20Kotlin%20Multiplatform/03_CreatingSharedCode :

```
package com.jetbrains.handson.mpp.mobile

expect fun platformName(): String

fun createApplicationScreenMessage(): String {
    return "Kotlin Rocks on ${platformName()}"
}
```

and Dart code

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _helloText = "...";
  static const MethodChannel methodChannel =
      MethodChannel('com.jetbrains.handson.mpp.mobile/createApplicationScreenMessage');

  Future<void> _getHello() async {
    final String result = await methodChannel.invokeMethod("getHello");
    setState(() {
      _helloText = result;
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    _getHello();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(_helloText),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tried flutter clean,app reinstall,project clean&build and nothing works for me, what reasons of this issue can be?

**UPD:** I don't know should my activity output this log through *Logcat* in configureFlutterEngine method or not but it doesn't. android.util.Log("tagdbg","Im here")

In Android Manifest I specified `<activity android:name=".MainActivity">` but not FlutterActivity as in official docs, but I need to get access to kotlin code from kotlin/native.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've made it work but don't know exactly what solution effected. I can advice to make it work only on Flutter at first(using MethodChannel from official flutter docs) and then try to do it with kotlin multiplatform. Also I used flutterEngine.dartExecutor instead of flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger

Comment: changing to flutterEngine.dartExecutor worked for me too, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Reason is miss super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)？
My code is similiar to yours, and it works ok:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    MyMethodChannel.register(this, flutterEngine)
}
```

}

Comment: This solves my issue!
Tks =)

Answer (score 0):

> Let's try this in your terminal

```
flutter run
```

Comment: I still get this exception and now in terminal. Check my update, maybe it can help to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this exception may be that your *MethodChannel* was not successfully registered, or you actively called *result.notImplemented()*,

1. please at `protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){}` inside registered.
2. in the case of Java code, replace `call.method == "xxx"` with `call.method.equals("xxx")`.

Please check if *onMethodCall* is called，Use this to locate the probleml.

Comment: can you break down sentences and make it proper to red and understand,